# create sql table with Sub columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to create SQL table with sub-columns like the below table format?

```
    Runs            Wickets             Speed
Min Max Avg Sum   Min Max Avg Sum   Min Max Avg Sum
```

3 main columns and 4 sub-columns(Min, Max, Avg, Sum) for each main column.

Comment: A table has rows and columns only. Why you need it?

Comment: No, a table has two dimensions; rows and columns. Both are non-fungible

Comment: @serg No initially i need to create table only. After that, i send data from API to created sql table.

Comment: if you have MySQL 8 you could consider using [Document Store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html)

Comment: DBMS servers does not deal with data representation, they only stores and processes the data. Such feature as columns combining is client's data displaying subsystem function.

Comment: That looks like nested tables, but I don't think MySQL has them. For the purpose of calculating values based on other values, it's probably not a good solution.

Comment: I really don't know what is your idea, but why not try with table structure: RunsMin, RunsMax, RunsAvg, RunsSum, WicketsMin, WicketsMax, ... etc.?

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks all, I think a better way to do this is create 4 separate tables instead of one table.

Comment: *I think a better way to do this is create 4 separate tables instead of one table.* This is bad idea which contradicts data normalizing.

Answer (score 0):

use like this its perfect way use in MYSQL with relation friendliness ..

[image]

Comment: You should post this a text, not as an image.

Comment: What do you mean by "like this"? What makes this "relation friendly"?

Comment: user can make forgein key for this "any_relation_key" column.